# Restrict insert into column with default value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Taking the following schema as an example:

```
CREATE TABLE public."RiskHeaders"
(
    "UID" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "Name" character varying(35) NOT NULL
)
```

**Is it possible to prevent `INSERT` statements including values for the `UID` column?**

For avoidance of doubt, I wish for all values within the `UID` column to be randomly generated via the default value function.

I had hoped that I could use an INSERT trigger to see whether `UID` had been populated but that doesn't appear to be possible:

```
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        IF TG_WHEN = 'BEFORE' THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'Before: Old = %    New = %', OLD."UID", NEW."UID";
        ELSIF TG_WHEN = 'AFTER' THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'After: Old = %    New = %', OLD."UID", NEW."UID";
        END IF;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Running `INSERT INTO "RiskHeaders"("Name") VALUES ('Test');` gives the following console output:

```
NOTICE:  Before: Old = <NULL>    New = ccc6757f-d1a2-4849-828d-017d2b738c9d
NOTICE:  After: Old = <NULL>    New = ccc6757f-d1a2-4849-828d-017d2b738c9d
```

Running `INSERT INTO "RiskHeaders"("UID", "Name") VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), 'Test1');` gives the same output (albeit with a different UUID).

Thank you in advance for any suggestions and hopefully this isn't too daft a question!

---

Many thanks for all the suggestions!

Given my (reckless?) determination to keep the `UID` column as a `uuid` type and prevent the user from specifying any values on `INSERT`, I have come up with the following work-around(/bodge):

I am now using the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public."RiskHeaders"
(
    "UID" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid,
    "Name" character varying(35) NOT NULL
}
```

Taking @stickybit's suggestion to use a trigger... I have come up with a trigger to the effect of:

```
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
        IF TG_WHEN = 'BEFORE' THEN
            IF NEW."UID" <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'A UID cannot be specified when creating a risk.';
            ELSE
                NEW."UID" := uuid_generate_v4();
                RETURN NEW;             
            END IF;
            ...
        END IF;
    END IF;
    ...
```

The drawbacks from this are:

- The schema doesn't make it clear that UIDs are actually being randomly assigned.
- The user could specify a zero UID which would then get silently replaced.

Comment: Hmm, might be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why would it be bad if the value was generated and inserted from "outside"?

Comment: I had never heard of the XY problem before so have learnt something there! My "thinking" (I use the term loosely) is that the user should have no reason at all to specify a `UID` value on record creation and was hoping there could be a way for this to be enforced. Frankly, this would be more of a 'nice to have'. However, I was still curious to know if it was feasible.

Comment: Hmm, first thing that comes into my mid would be brute force: Create a trigger that generates the UUID and simply overwrites any one given in the triggering `INSERT`.

Comment: @RMills330 normally an uuid shouldn't repeat at all, so it wouldn't be really a problem to let the clients generate their own. You an enforce it with a trigger, but it sounds imho a little unnecessary. If you can afford to identify your rows with `bigint` values, you can create a `generated always as identity` column. Doing so the database will raise an exception everytime a client tries to insert a value in the column ;) -> `CREATE TABLE public."RiskHeaders" (myid bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, name text)`

Comment: @JimJones Understood... I also want to prevent them from conciously re-using one that has previously been deleted (but that they somehow still have knowledge of). Yours is another great idea but I'd like to stick to UUIDs for this particular project. That aside, I wasn't aware of this `generated always as identity` functionality and will make a note to check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @stickybit Just reflecting over your suggestion... I agree that it would enable me to overwrite any UID that they've specified. However, in terms of the specific question/schema, it sounds as though this just isn't possible without a change in column data type. (Which could well be the answer to this question)

Comment: @RMills330 so I believe a trigger is the best option for you :) happy coding +1

Comment: @RMills330: I don't see why this required a change of the data type. It would effectively "shadow" the `DEFAULT` clause though. Or in other words you would sort of (re)implement that yourself in the trigger. But you might even do some voodoo by getting the `DEFAULT` clause from the catalog and (dynamically) execute that in the trigger...

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it sounds as though there are two possible approaches: 1) Change data type as required to use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` functionality.  Or... 2) Use the `BEFORE` trigger to overwrite any such `UID` specified during `INSERT` but I wouldn't have any way to identify whether one was already specified and tell the user off for doing it. Point is... It sounds as though what I'm asking can't be done without a compromise of some sort.